# ブラケットでエラーになる理由は？

Tags: javascript

**エラーにならない**

```
var test = {}; 
test.p = function(){
  var hoge = {v : 1, d : 2};
  return hoge;
}
```

---

**エラー**

```
var test = {}; 
test[p] = function(){
  var hoge = {v : 1, d : 2};
  return hoge;
}
```

> Uncaught ReferenceError: p is not defined(…)

---

**エラーにならない**

```
var test = {}; 
var p;
test[p] = function(){
  var hoge = {v : 1, d : 2};
  return hoge;
}
```

---

**質問**
・この違いはどうして生じるのでしょうか？

Comment: 必要なのは`test["p"]` ではありませんか？ `test[p]`だと変数pの内容をキーとしたtestの要素になります。

Comment: なるほど、test[p]だと、pはプロパティ名ではないわけですね。参考になりました

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`test.p` と等しい数式は `test['p']` です。又は

```
var test = {}
var key = 'p';
test[key] = function() { /* ... */ };
```

も同じです。

`test[p]` は、`p` という変数の値を文字列に変更し、キーとして `test` からプロパティを取り出すことです。だから `p` の定義がなければ、`test[p]` の値の評価ができません。

MDN のドキュメンテーション「[オブジェクトを利用する](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)」もご覧ください 。

Comment: 質問した時点では全く気が付きませんでした。説明大変分かりやすかったです